# Dagger2 component generic inject method

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I converted my app from Dagger1.0 to dagger2.0, and have an app component with many `void inject(Activity/Fragment/Receiver/etc object)` methods.

With dagger 1.0 I just could just do `objectGraph.inject(Object object)` but now my component has to have a method for every single class that gets dependencies injected to it.

Why can't I just have a component that has one method: `<T> void inject(T t);` ?

For reference:
**My component right now:**

```
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(MyFirstActivity activity);

    void inject(MySecondActivity activity);

    void inject(MyFirstFragment fragment);

    void inject(MySecondFragment fragment);

    ...
}
```

**The component I want:**

```
public interface AppComponent {
   <T> void inject(T object);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Why can't I just have a component that has one method: `<T> void inject(T t);`?

Because `dagger-2` uses code generation and needs to know the type information at compile time. Without it, there is no way to tell which dependencies `T` would need—therefore code generation would be impossible.

If you compile your first component and check out the generated `Dagger*Component` source code, you will see that each `inject` method gets its own factory method, providing all of the dependencies *for the given type*.

This is the same for injecting subclasses. You can check out the paragraph *[A note about covariance](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html)* in the component documentation. Because the superclass type is known, dagger can inject members in the superclass, but it will not inject members of potential subtypes. Again, because `dagger-2` relies on compile time code generation this is not possible.

Comment: but with Dagger1, I could do `objectGraph.inject(anyObject)` or call `get(clazz)` with any class: `<T> T get(Class<T> clazz)`

Comment: I have to admit I never looked at dagger1 closely

Comment: Dagger 1 works with reflection at runtime, not code generation, so it has all the information it needs to invoke a generic method