# Is there a compile-time dependency injection tool that supports generics for kotlin (or java)?

Tags: java, kotlin, dependency-injection

All runtime DI (guice, spring, koin, kodein) do support generics.

Dagger 2 - which is only DI compile-time tool that I know - doesn't support generics.

Is there a compile-time dependency injection tool that supports generics for kotlin (or java)?

EDIT: Sample:

```
class Engine<T>

class Car<T> @Inject constructor(engine: Engine<T>)
```

If I'll use Dagger 2 and create:

```
@Module
object MyModule
{
    @Provides
    fun <T> car(engine: Engine<T>): Car<T> = Car(engine)
}

@Component(modules = [MyModule::class])
interface MyComponent
{
    fun <T> car(): Car<T>
}
```

It will not work because Dagger 2 will at compile time say, that methods with @Provide cannot be of a generic type

Comment: Why do you say Dagger doesn't support generics?

Comment: @LouisWasserman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784511/dagger2-component-generic-inject-method

Comment: with Hilt you don't need component classes and therefore don't need inject methods

Comment: @IR42 Hilt works only on Android (let me know if I'm wrong, never used it)

Comment: Have you investigated [Micronaut](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#ioc)? I don't know about its generics support.

Comment: @jaco0646 micronaut is just a specification and is much wider than just CDI, and also all (known to me) implementations of CDI are runtime. If you believe that I'm missing any implementation then please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to [some code changes](https://github.com/evant/kotlin-inject/pull/121) in their repository, it seems that [kotlin-inject](https://github.com/evant/kotlin-inject) does support generics in general.